# How would I consistently convert an indexed triangle data structure to a triangle strip data structure?

Tags: arrays, c, 3d

I wanted to do some data experimenting with triangles but all of my reference data uses indexed triangle lists.

To keep it simple, say I have four points in 3D Space that create two triangles, denoted by V1, V2, V3, V4.

The vertex data would be:

```
0 = v1 data
1 = v2 data
2 = v3 data
3 = v4 data
```

and the triangle data is now

```
0, 1, 2
2, 1, 3
```

[Image of that is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfRXi.png)

I would like to simplify this data structure so that it is in a strip. Based on my reading, I assume it is something like this:

```
0 1 2 3
```

I loosely understand how to process the strip data, but now the question would be how do I get from my current data to that strip structure consistently if I have a bunch of triangles in any particular order. At what point would I define the "start" of my strip?

I looked at the example in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/triangle-strips

All the reading I have done has mostly just been to say "Don't use triangle strips" and I understand that it may not be more optimized or anything like that, this is simply to have a better grasp of the evolution.

Comment: AFAIK, finding optimal solution to the shortest sequence of triangle strips is NP-complete because it can be mapped to Hamiltonian Cycle/Path problem

Comment: @David W – 
Why do _four points in 3D Space_ only _create two triangles_?

Comment: @Armali The triangles are being rendered as 2D objects, but the coordinates are in 3D space. This is for rendering the surface mesh of a 3D object. Should've specified. Using four points is just a quick example, but the actual usage has over 5000 triangles

Comment: Still I don't understand why with _two triangles_ (however arbitrary derived from _four points_) you have three _triangle data_, and why the combination `0, 2, 3` is not among the data.

Comment: Why does the triangle data include three triangles when you wrote you were creating two triangles?

Comment: Per the article you link to, a triangle strip is a sequence of triangles determined from a sequence of points, where the first triangle is formed from the first three points and each subsequent triangle is formed from the previous two points and the next point. Therefore, if you had a list of triangles as a list of all three points of each triangle, and it satisfied the requirement for a triangle strip (that each subsequent triangle have two points in common with the previous one), you would construct the list of points for a triangle strip by…

Comment: … listing the points of the first triangle and followed by the new point of each subsequent triangle. So that would seem to be the answer to your question, and the details depend on particulars of how you have the starting list of triangles, which you have not shown.

Comment: Re “how do I get from my current data to that strip structure consistently if I have a bunch of triangles in any particular order”: You need to order the triangles into a sequence in which each subsequent triangle shares two points with the prior one. If your question is how to do that, you should reword your Stack Overflow post and provide details about how the data is managed and how it is known that the triangles satisfy the requirements for a triangle strip yet their ordering for that has been lost.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your answer seems to be what I was looking for, as this question was mostly a conceptual one. If I have issues creating code, I will probably make a new question.